# Can't get value using dot notation

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure

The code works perfect with WHITESPACE_ONLY option. But in ADVANCED mode dot notation doesn't work. But bracket notation still does work.

Here is JSON object:

```
{
    'title' : 'The title',
    'type' : 'SIM',
    'description' : 'Build your own description.',
    'iconclass' : goog.getCssName('img-icons-bs')
}
```

Here is the code:

```
console.log('this.obj_ = ' + JSON.stringify(this.obj_));
console.log('this.obj_.iconclass = ' + this.obj_.iconclass);
console.log('this.obj_[iconclass] = ' + this.obj_['iconclass']);
```

Output:

```
> this.obj_ = {"title":"The title","type":"SIM","description":"Build 
> your own description.","iconclass":"img-icons-r"}
> this.obj_.iconclass = undefined
> this.obj_[iconclass] = img-icons-r
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Are you still getting that if you try again? And have you checked for little typos, even a case change like `.iconClass` ?

Comment: @SmokeyPHP, Yes, I've checked it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you [understand the differences between the compilation modes](http://closuretools.blogspot.com/2012/09/which-compilation-level-is-right-for-me.html).

In ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, closure-compiler renames properties which are referenced by dotted notation and does not rename properties using quoted notation. Example:

**Original**:

```
var foo = {};
foo.bar = foo['bar'] = 47;
```

**Compiled**

```
var a = {};
a.b = a.bar = 47;
```

Since the JSON object properties are hidden from the compiler, you must access them always using quoted notation.

```
// This line is incorrect - the compiler can rename '.iconclass'
console.log('this.obj_.iconclass = ' + this.obj_.iconclass);

// This line is correct - ["iconclass"] is safe from renaming.
console.log('this.obj_[iconclass] = ' + this.obj_['iconclass']);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is returning undefined for the following line as you never defined `game`. Check the output again. You have read it the wrong way around.

```
console.log('this.obj_[iconclass] = ' + this.game_['iconclass']);
```

If you change the lines to the following it will work for both bracket and dot notation:

```
console.log('this.obj_.iconclass = ' + this.obj_.iconclass);
console.log('this.obj_[iconclass] = ' + this.obj_['iconclass']);
```

[image]

Comment: game_ is typo. Originally its obj_. Problem still exist.